# Oddity with _.isEqual(obj1,obj2)

Tags: lodash

I'm using Lodash in a project where I need to compare two objects, one an original version and the other a possibly modified version of it, which I need to test to see if it's 'dirty' (i.e., has been modified at all).

Clearly, Lodash's _.isEqual() would seem to be the perfect candidate for this. Except it's telling me the two objects are not equal even though I'm pretty certain they are. If I do a JSON.stringify on both objects, the strings are equal, so how can it even be possible that the two objects are not equal?

Comment: They probaly are not equal. Stringifying is really not a good way to check. Show us the objects!

Comment: I believe `JSON.stringify(a)=== JSON.stringify(b)` is in fact one of the standard ways of testing the equality of two objects. In fact, I could use this and forgo _.isEqual() altogether, but I'd just like to know what the problem is. The objects are quite 'deep' and I'm not sure how to show them here without representing them in JSON - in which case they would be shown to be equal.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is not very safe considering that it is very sensitive to ordering, which can be random. People use it but convering objects to strings is not the way to compare objects. The problem is probably some specific property that is not safe to be compared using `===`, e.g dates or something that is not a plain object. You might want to find a "diff" function in some library and try to diff the two objects. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-diff, for example.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the ordering issue, but that would result in false negatives, not false positives. That is, two objects being reported as different when in fact they're the same, just ordered differently. What I'm seeing here is the opposite, though - the JSON representations are reported as equal but the objects themselves are reported as different by Lodash. I do not understand how that can be possible.

Comment: As I said, objects converted to string can be the same but that does not imply they are the same.

Comment: Thanks for that, I think I've learned something useful there. I discovered, looking at my code, that I was mixing-and-matching - I copied the object using `var obj2=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1))` but compared them later using `_.isEqual(obj1,obj2)`. Having switched to using _.cloneDeep for the copy now, the objects are showing as equal with _.isEqual(). It doesn't really matter which I use, for my purposes, I just have to use the same technique (JSON or Lodash) in copy and compare.